# how to replace or find correct path for kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize, livenessprobe

I have deployment and I want to replace "path" value in liveness probe section. What is correct path for this in kustomize?

```
- patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: ??????????
      value:
        https://xyz.staging.something.eu/ping
```

---

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        test: liveness
      name: liveness-http
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: liveness
        image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
        args:
        - /server
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the yaml path. You follow the nodes from the parent down to the leaf-node you want to specify.

Since you want the `path` node on `httpGet` of `livenessProbe` it will end with `livenessProbe.httpGet.path`.

The parent node of livenessProbe is a bit trickier, notice it is an element of the list `containers`. You can specify it either through an index or through an attribute (EG `name`). So either `containers[0]` or `containers[name=liveness]`.

By now we have `containers[0].livenessProbe.httpGet.path`. The missing root node is `spec`, so `spec.containers[0].livenessProbe.httpGet.path` will do it.

There is a bunch of other ways that this could be expressed as well.
https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath#illustration seems like a good more in-depth explanation.

Comment: What version of kustomize are you using to make this work? According to the docs (https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_patchesjson6902_), the patch document needs to be an RFC6902 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) compliant document. In turn, that says that the `path` property needs to be an RFC6901 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6901) JSON pointer which only supports array addressing using indexes.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying out the syntax `containers[name=xx]` and its failing  when `containers/0` works. I am not sure if im missing something or this is not supported, couldn't find any more examples about this syntax for Kustomize.

Below the details

Checked with kustomize versions:

- v4.5.4
- v4.5.2

test.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      env:
      - name: environment
        value: stage
      - name: api_port
        value: "8080"
      image: docker.io/bitname/posgresql:latest
      ...
      ...
```

kustomization.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

...
...

patchesJson6902:
- target:
    version: v1
    kind: Pod
    name: test-pod
  path: replace.yaml
```

replace.yaml

```yaml
- op: replace
  path: "/spec/containers[name=test-container]/env/0/value"
  value: "dev"
# doesn't work: `Error: replace operation does not apply: doc is missing path" /spec/containers[name=test-container]/env/0/value: missing value
 

- op: replace
  path: "/spec/containers/0/env/0/value"
  value: "dev"
# works as expected
```

Thanks!